# Jquery droppable out function

Tags: jquery, droppable, out

Why the alert in the out trigger is not displayed?

The dop trigger is working fine, but out trigger isn't:

```
$(".ui-droppable").droppable( {
    accept: '#cardPile div',
    hoverClass: 'hovered',
    drop: function(event, ui){
        $(this).droppable('disable' );
        ui.draggable.position( { of: $(this), my: 'left top', at: 'left top' } );
        ui.draggable.draggable('option', 'revert', false);
    },
    out: function(event, ui){
        alert("test");
    }
});
```

I'm new on this...
Thanks!

Comment: So are you saying when you drag an element into the droppable zone and then try to drag it out of that zone the trigger is not firing?

Answer (score 0):

I've had problems with the JQuery UI droppable `out` method before too.  I got around them by using the `deactivate` method instead.  Although I expected this only to fire when I stopped dragging the dragged element, it in fact fired when I moved out of the droppable whilst still dragging, which sounds like what you need.